# how to access variable from controller to model

Tags: php

hello i have a problem with CodeIgniter.
i want to access a variable from controller to model because my query need id 
this is my controller code

```
<?php
class C_Moshakhsat extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $data['Todos']=$this->M_Moshakhsat->moshakhsat_list();
        $this->load->view('V_Moshakhsat',$data);
        $product_id = $this->input->get('id', TRUE);    
    }
}
```

?>

and this is my model code

```
<?php
class M_Moshakhsat extends CI_Model{
    public function moshakhsat_list(){

        $query="SELECT customer_name , order_date , saled_product_price , saled_product_quantity, product_name ,saled_product_price*saled_product_quantity as ss FROM customer c ,orders o ,order_detail d , product p WHERE p.produt_id=d.product_id and o.order_id=d.order_id and c.customer_id=o.order_id and o.order_id=product_id";
        $res=$this->db->query($query);
        return $res->result();

    }   

        }
```

?>
i want to get id from url and pass them in to query i don't know how?

Comment: Your code will need restructuring - the `$this->input->get()` should be the first line in your controller function, and should be passing the result as an argument to the model. The [Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) class might also be helpful for simple queries like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just send the id as function argument to the model:

```
class C_Moshakhsat extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $product_id = $this->input->get('id', TRUE);
        $data['Todos']=$this->M_Moshakhsat->moshakhsat_list($product_id);
        $this->load->view('V_Moshakhsat',$data);

    }
}
```

And in the model:

```
 public function moshakhsat_list($product_id)
    {
      //mysql connections
    }
```

You should parse the sql query to avoid the Mysql injection for this use the CI query builder class for making mysql queries .

Comment: tanks dear do you have facebook or mail address for more contact